# radioButtons() vs. uiOutput() and observeEvent(input[[""]] - shiny

Tags: shiny, observers, uioutput

I try to observe an event in shiny. If I define a radio manually, it will be observed correctly - output: `print(paste0("SELECT * FROM daten;"))`. I want to avoid writing several tenths of radio buttons in ui.r. Thus I wrote a loop in the server part.
But the same observeEvent() does not react on my "loop-listed" radio buttons which where correctly built in shiny app. I have no idea why.

I wrote a minimal example:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    
    ####### manually set radio #######
    print("This radio 'pd1' will be observed:"),
    radioButtons(inputId = "pd1", label = "value:", choices = c("?", "0", "1")),
    br(), br(),
    
    ####### versus looped set set radio #######
    
    uiOutput("scrlst"),
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    tablscr <- data.frame("1","question")
    
    ###################### observeEvent
    ##### "counter" for several items (in this case just 1 item)
    rv <- reactiveValues(counter = 0)
    lapply(1:dim(tablscr)[1], function(i) {
      isolate({qnum <- paste0('pd', rv$counter <- rv$counter + 1)})
      observeEvent(input[[qnum]], {print(paste0("SELECT * FROM daten;"))})
    })
    
    ### output for tenths of items in one loop  (in this case just 1 item)
    output$scrlst <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        scr <- list(),
        for (sq in 1:dim(tablscr)[1]){
          scr[[sq]] = list(sq,
                           print("This radio 'pd1' will not be observed:"),
                           radioButtons(inputId = "pd1", label = "value:", choices = c("?", "0", "1")),
                           br(),
                           br()
          )
        },
        return(scr),
      )
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: in the loop, all your `f7Radio`s have the same ID.  That won't work.  They all need to have unique ids.  Rather than trying to manage these unique IDs yourself in the main server, convert `f7Radio` to a [module](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) and allow Shiny to do the grunt work for you.  Also, in your `renderUI`, `cr <- list()` and `return(scr)` appear to be inside the `tagList()`.  That unlikely to be right...  You're more likely to get help if you provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Oh yes: welcome to SO!

Comment: thank you! i edited my post a little and added a minimal example. don't care about the id's. this is just for example (and to monitor what happens). in reality there is a counter.

Comment: oh well, i set `scr <- list()` and `return(scr)` outside the loop. but it does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `tagList` containing a loop and a return statement sounds weird. Moreover you have a duplicated id `pd1`. Here is a working code:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    
    uiOutput("scrlst")
    
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    tablscr <- data.frame(c("1","2"), c("question", "hello"))
    
    lapply(1:nrow(tablscr), function(i) {
      qnum <- paste0('pd', i)
      observeEvent(input[[qnum]], {print(paste0("SELECT * FROM daten;"))})
    })
    
    output$scrlst <- renderUI({
      do.call(tagList, lapply(1:nrow(tablscr), function(i){
        tagList(
          radioButtons(paste0("pd", i), label = "value:", choices = c("?", "0", "1")),
          br(), br()
        )
      }))
    })
    
  }
)
```

Comment: this is great! it workes. thx!!
is there a chance to have two radios with the same inputid beeing observed?